# Splitting out pem key into CA, Cert and Key

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, private-key, pem

I have been supplied with a signed certificate in .pem format and wanted to know if there was a way to split it into 3 separate files for CA, Cert and Key? I need to ingest this into Vault using IAC and a series of scripts and the method/code we are using requires 3 separate files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The format of the key is as follows. I can establish that the first block is the private key but not sure how to establish the other blocks? is there a way using OpenSSL I can determine this?

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
----- END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"... a signed .pem key ..."* - not clear what you mean by this. Please provide more details on what you actually got, i.e. the full line for all the BEGIN and END labels in your file.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i just updated my initial post with the format of my .pem file

Comment: The first part is the key, the next three parts are certificates. The order is unknown but very likely the first is the server certificate and the others are chain certificates. You can use a simple editor (i.e. something like vi or notepad, not MS Office) to extract everything you need into separate files (just copy + paste or so).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for the quick reply. I was thinking the same in terms of extracting the certs but if I get the ordering or specify the certificate type incorrectly surely that would cause an issue? is there no smart way of identifying for sure which portion is the chain, CA etc?

Comment: *" is there no smart way of identifying for sure which portion is the chain, CA etc?"* - Separate each certificate into its own file. Use some certificate viewer (or `openssl x509 -in file.pem -text -noout`) to look at subject and issuer and make sure that the issuer of certificate#1 is the subject of certificate#2 etc. The server certificate should also contain a subject alternative names section which contains the domain names the certificate is for.

Comment: Run the file through `openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile CHAINED.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text -noout` (where `CHAINED.pem` is your file).  This will ignore the private key and list the certificates in order.